# Mod_rewrite and multiple variable in different order

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

I'm new to StackOverflow so I'll try my best to be as clear as possible. I'm rewriting my URLs to be more SEO friendly, so I looked into mod_rewrite and thought it might be the best way to go. I am working on an ecommerce website (that detail has its importance later).
So when it comes to simple pages like `/about_us.php`, it's pretty easy to redirect .

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about-us/$ /about_us.php
```

I think we all agree on this one. The problem arises when I try to rewrite the URL on my filter page. So on a page like

```
example.com/examplefile.php?filter1=a&filterb=2&filterc=3
```

It's still easy to redirect. (NB: I chose to write "filter1" before the value)

```
RewriteRule ^/products/filter1-([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/filter2-([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/filter3-([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /examplefile.php?filter1=$1&filterb=$2&filterc=$3
```

Here is the part I stumble on: it is possible that the filters might be in a different order, let's say

```
example.com/examplefile.php?filterb=2&filter1=a&filterc=3
```

No way I'm going to write all the possibilities in `.htaccess`, since I have 6 different filters, and that you can use either 1,2,3... to 6filters, ordered or not, it's ... a lot of possibilities (i'll let you do the maths ;) ).

Do you have any solution with mod_rewrite, or maybe with something else? I'm thinking 301 Redirect, but my concern is how the links are going to appear in search engines.. I'm getting my hands on SEO, but some parts are still a mistery to me (I guess that's what wizard Google wants!)

Answer (score 1):

From a SEO standpoint you shouldn't have multiple URls with the same content, so you should not create links like `/filter1-42/filter2-42/` and `/filter2-42/filter1-42/` on the site if they give the same results ([canonical url](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=hu&answer=139394) link tag might help with external sources linking to your site).

***edit:*** removed 'filter' from the patterns, to make it more generalized.

I would break the problem in half and the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^/products/((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[-a-zA-Z0-9]+/?)*) /products.php?filterstr=$1
```

and handle the `filterstr` parsing in php like this:

```
$filters = array();
$filterparts = explode('/', trim(isset($_GET['filterstr']) ? $_GET['filterstr'] : '', '/'));
foreach ($filterparts as $filter) {
    if (preg_match('/(?<key>\w+)-(?<value>[-a-z0-9]+)/i', $filter, $m)) {
        $filters[$m['key']] = $m['value'];
    }
}
```

This should make this url:

```
http://example.com/products/language-france-and-stuff/filtera-42/filter1-42/filterb-42/
```

output:

```
array(4) { 'language' => string(6) "france" 'filtera' => string(2) "42" 'filter1' => string(2) "42" 'filterb' => string(2) "42" }
```

The idea is that every url segment after the first one is a `/<name>-<value>/` pair where a `<name>` can't include a `-` and `/`, and the `<value>` can't include a `/`

Copying that pattern to every single place you need it would create a maintenance hell if you need it say 10 places, so at this point I would try to introduce some structure to whole parameter handling and create a [front controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html), that would parse the whole `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and select the controller and pass the parameters in some standard way down to it, so you need only one `RewriteRule` in your `.htaccess`, and everything else is up to the application (for added bonus it's easier to debug there).

Comment: yes that's what i thought..i'll try your solution and keep you updated. thanks!

Comment: Another question, with your method, would it be possible to link my DB to the URL,i.e if i have (for example) country=5 but i want to display /country-france

Comment: edit: you have a typo on your line 2
$filterparts = explode('/', trim(isset($_GET['filterstr']) ? $_GET['filterstr'] : ''));

Comment: Fixed the typo, and made the solution more generalized with an added footnote of front controllers.